# UIImage stretching for unknown reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

**EDIT:** This only happens in the phone. It works fine in the simulator.

I am having a weird issue that I can't seem to rectify.

In the app I am building you can add and replace a profile photo and here is what is happening.

When you either select an image from your library or take a new one with the camera, you are returned to your profile view and you can see the new image.

Here it is with a temp image.

[image]

But when I go back to the main nav and then return to the profile page, the image is wider than it should be.

[image]

I am at a real loss here. The code to call each image is virtually identical.

```
// Code after initial image selection

UIImage *image = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
profileImage.image = image;


//Code after returning to the page.

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:directoryWithProfilePicName];
profileImage.image = image;
```

Any thoughts would be great.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
// Creating directoryWithProfilePicName.

NSString *localDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *profilePicName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", profilePic];  
NSString *directoryWithProfilePicName = [localDirectory stringByAppendingString:profilePicName];

// Creating the image view.

#define IS_IPHONE5 (([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height-568)?NO:YES)

if (IS_IPHONE5) {
    profileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 335, 300)];
} else {
    profileImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 60, 335, 210)];
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

```
- (void)takeNewPhotoFromCamera {
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    controller.allowsEditing = NO;
    controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
}

-(void)choosePhotoFromExistingImages {
    UIImagePickerController *controller = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    controller.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    controller.allowsEditing = NO;
    controller.mediaTypes = [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController presentViewController: controller animated: YES completion: nil];
}


- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated: YES completion: nil];
    NSString *uuidString = [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString];

    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.jpg", uuidString];
    UIImage *image = [info valueForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1.0)];

    NSLog(@"Pic Name: %@", imageName);
    NSLog(@"Image Size: %f x %f", image.size.width, image.size.height);
    NSLog(@"picture Taken.");

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
    [UIView saveNewPhoto:imageName forPetID:pIDint];

    profileImage.image = image;
    profileImage.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}
```

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: Didn't realize it, but auto layout was checked. I unchecked it and there was no change.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is caused by your UIImageView's content mode.

```
theImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Make sure you are using ScaleAspectFit, otherwise your UIImageView will default to  UIViewContentModeScaleToFill.

Comment: I thought so too. But no matter what I set as the content mode, it is always wider when I return to the screen.

Comment: Can I see the code for "directoryWithProfilePicName"? Also can I see how you created your UIImageView?

Comment: And this doesn't happen when it's in the simulator? Very weird.

Comment: Yeah, the simulator is fine. And any images that ship with the app are fine. It seems like what is shown from the camera is not the same as what is being saved, but NSLogging shows that they are the identical size.

I added UPDATE 1: above.

Comment: Very strange, I literally use near identical code to this in one of my apps and it works fine, I'll update if I figure anything out.

Comment: Wait so this only happens when taking a photo? If so can I see your code for capturing a photo?

Comment: UPDATE 2 has the code. It happens when taking a photo or when choosing from the library. And like I said it looks fine initially. But when I return to the page I am getting what is saved, not the image straight from the camera/library.

Comment: Try UIImage *image = (UIImage *) [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

Comment: Did you figure anything out?

Comment: Sorry, had to go for a bit. Suggestion didn't change anything. I am going to hack around with it some more now.

Comment: I have no idea why, but if I make the box ImageView in storyboards it works fine. Even if I put both views on the screen at the same time and load the same image, the image in the SB view is fine and the programmatic one is stretched.